# Webflow: How to Use Custom Short Links?

Tags: url-shortener, webflow

Recently, a client asked me to shorten the link of a page, and one of the requests was as follows:

"A page like this https://www.example.com/team-and-members could also just be example.com/staff."

Is this possible? Has anyone done something similar in Webflow?

I've come across third-party options like Rebrandly, but it seems a bit complex, and I'm not sure if it works seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same behavior of a Custom short link manager by setting up custom 301 redirects in your webflow website.

How to do it :
webflow dashboard > Your site settings > Publishing > Scroll down to 301 redirects

[image: 301 menu in Webflow]

The correct way to handle redirection is to put your new shortened link in the old path, and the correct link in the redirect to path.

example: old path : `/staff` -> Redirect to path : `/team-and-members`

Hope this helps !